# Common Collector Amplifier DC Analysis (why not get the VTH and RTH like in Thevenin's Theorem?)

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, dc, bjt, emitter-follower

I looked in the book of Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory and in the section of a common collector amplifier configuration with a voltage divider, it shows that:
$$ V_B=\frac{VCCR_2}{R_1+R_2} $$

However on other voltage divider amplifiers with a collector resistor the solution is:
$$ V_{TH} =\frac{VCCR_2}{R_1+R_2} $$

and to get \$ V_B, \$ the solution to be used is \$ V_B = V_{TH}-I_BR_{TH} \$

Obviously, both will yield a different answer. So I was wondering if why the first formula above must be used instead of applying Thevenin's Theorem (VTH, RTH)?

It can't be because of the voltage divider approximation which is \$ \beta R_E \ge 10R_2\$, I calculated it but \$ 10R_2 \$ is still bigger and it still uses the first formula.

I searched for youtube tutorial videos and no one explained why. Here's the schematic and the solution: (There's also on YouTube if that's needed)

[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmTE_Qf2K9M)

[image: Emitter-follower circuit]

[image: solution]

Comment: Schematic please???? There is a schematic editor available to you within your question editing features here. Help us help you!

Comment: @jonk I already added it

Comment: Do you think it might help in interpreting your equation to ***label*** your components??? I mean, I might guess at \$R_1\$. But I'd rather not. That said, I think I know what to say. But I think it would still improve your question to label things.

Comment: @jonk Oh, I'm sorry for that. I revised it again.

Comment: The first formula neglects the base current - a rather rough approximation because Ib=66µA and the divider current is less than 120µA

Comment: @LvW I noticed that too and by simulation, the value with a base current is much closer to the measured value. I just wonder why websites, videos, and a solution manual would provide a formula like that.

Comment: Another example which shows that it is dangerous to blindly believe what is written  in some textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic is roughly this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRfSUe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the same as (using a Thevenin divider approach):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu3Lrg.png)</sup>

From this it is easy to work out (from KVL) that:

$$V_\text{TH}-I_B\cdot R_\text{TH}-V_{\text{BE}_1}-I_E\cdot R_\text{E}=0\:\text{V}$$

But also you know that \$I_E=\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_B\$ so it follows that:

$$V_\text{TH}-I_B\cdot R_\text{TH}-V_{\text{BE}_1}-\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_B\cdot R_\text{E}=0\:\text{V}$$

And therefore that:

$$I_B=\frac{V_\text{TH}-V_{\text{BE}_1}}{R_\text{TH}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_\text{E}}$$

This means that if \$\beta\ge 100\$ then \$I_b\le 63\:\mu\text{A}\$ and that \$V_B=V_\text{TH}-I_B\cdot R_\text{TH}\ge 8.36\:\text{V}\$.

(With \$\beta\ge 300\$ this works out to \$V_B\approx 9.06\:\text{V}\$.)

From there, you can work out the rest.

Comment: I clearly understand this but why on websites and videos that I search for and also the answer that I provided from my post (it is from a solution manual), ignored the base current? So it's just VB=VCC*RC/(R1+R2)?

Comment: @pxrry It would be really bad to ignore the base current if the resistor divider at the base has a high impedance, because of the voltage drop then caused. But most designs will set the divider to a *relatively* low impedance. Doing so means that the error in using that over-simple formula (the unaccounted voltage drop) is *relatively* small. Given that anything within 10% of where you think it is can be considered "good enough" and given  the complexity of trying to teach someone a harder-t--grasp formula, the simpler idea is often used instead.